# Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be real numbers such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$ Find the maximum value of $9x+12y+8z.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cauchy-sequences

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be real numbers such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$ Find the maximum value of $9x+12y+8z.$

---

We aren't given anything other than what $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is.  How can I manipulate that equation into something useful?  I'm stuck.  Any solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

$$9x+12y+8z \color{red}\leq \sqrt{9^2+12^2+8^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \color{red}{17} $$
and equality is achieved at $(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{17}\left(9,12,8\right).$

Comment: Very nice. I was thinking of Lagrange multipliers, but yours is much better.